# передать значение локальной переменной в другую функцию

Tags: c++, функции, типы-данных

Здравствуйте, имеется вот такая функция, рекурсивно получаю список файлов в директориях, возникла потребность передать директорию в другую функцию, типы соблюдаю `d_name` в который получаю имя директории с типом `char` передаю в `char`, только в другой функции как не мудрил с указателями получаю либо пустоту либо байт код, подскажите как правильно это сделать?

```
int getdir(string dir, vector<string> &files)
{
    // Указатель каталога
    DIR *dp;
    // Структура каталога
    struct dirent *dirp;
    // Попытаться открыть каталог
    if ((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
        return errno;
    }
    // Обход каждого файла в каталоге
    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        // Если обнаружен каталог, то рекурсивное чтение из него
        if (dirp->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(dirp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dirp->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            string p = dir + "/" + dirp->d_name;
            getdir(p, files);
        }
        // Пропуск скрытых файлов
        else if (dirp->d_type == DT_REG && string(dirp->d_name).substr(0, 1) == ".")
        {
            continue;
        }
        // Добавление файлов в список
        else if (dirp->d_type == DT_REG)
        {
            files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
        }
    }
    // Закрывает указать директории
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: при использовании отладчика я вижу, что `dirp->d_name` получает в виде переменной директорию вида "./Folder", а стоит сделать указатель или передать в виде аргумента, на выходе получаю пустоту или байт код, в этом то и заключается вопрос, я просто не могу понять почему

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, у вас ошибка в этой строке:

```
string p = dir + "/" + dirp->d_name;
```

`dirp->d_name`, имеет тип char*, строка  "/" неявно преобразуется в const char*, в итоге происходит сложение указателей, а не строк. Советую не мешать c и c++, и везде использовать std::string, ну или хотя бы приводить строки к ним. `strcmp` тоже лучше заменить на сравнение std::string.

А закрытие каталога лучше отдать под управление умного указателя:

```
using dir_ptr_t = std::unique_ptr<DIR, decltype(&closedir)>;
dir_ptr_t dp (opendir(dir.c_str()), &closedir); // Второй аргумент - указатель на функцию, которая осуществдляет удаление
if(dp){
  ...
}
```

EDIT: Оператор + всё же имеет ассоциативность слева на право, т. е. там будет неявное преобразование в std::string и строки сложатся правильно. Но лучше явно указывать, что указатель на char переводится в std::string.